# Foldl for truth with short circuiting

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I want to know if `f(X)` is true for all `X` in some very large list `L`.
Right now I have:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X, Last) -> f(X) andalso Last end, true, L)
```

The problem is I don't think this short circuits. Even if it is false for the first element in `L` it continues on always andalsoing with `false`.

Is there a flag to foldl such that this will short circuit or another function I can use?

I now see there is a function called `all` but it doesn't say whether it short circuits either.

Comment: `all` does short-circuit. it only takes 1 false to compute the answer for `all` – no need to keep evaluating beyond that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lists:foldl/3` does not have any way to stop the fold and return a value immediately. You can use [`lists:all/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#all-2) for this, which will stop processing the rest of the list if the function passed returns `false` for any item of the list:

```
lists:all(fun(X) -> f(X) end, L)

% or

lists:all(fun f/1, L)
```

Comment: maybe mention `all`'s counterpart, `any`